# Why do font files replace spaces with quotation marks in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
 @font-face {
   font-family: "TD Graphik SemiLight";
   src: url("https://tdloyalty.s3.amazonaws.com/web-fonts/TDGraphik-Semilight-Web.eot");
   src: url("https://tdloyalty.s3.amazonaws.com/web-fonts/TDGraphik-Semilight-Web.eot?#iefix")
       format("embedded-opentype"),
     url("https://tdloyalty.s3.amazonaws.com/web-fonts/TDGraphik-Semilight-Web.woff2")
       format("woff2"),
     url("https://tdloyalty.s3.amazonaws.com/web-fonts/TDGraphik-Semilight-Web.woff")
       format("woff");
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
 }
 body {
   font-family: 'TD Graphik SemiLight';
 }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
 <p>A sentence with spaces 29.00 %</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why do I see a quotation mark between the number zero and the percentage sign even though I just used a space?  Problem doesn't occur if I use a different font family.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's only happening when the `woff2` format is present.

Comment: Replace sentence: A sentence with spaces `29.00 %` with A sentence with spaces `29.00%`.

Comment: @NitinBisht While commonly omitted, both SI and ISO prescribe the use of a (non-breaking) space between numbers and the per cent sign. Incidentally, using `&nbsp;` fixes OP’s problem but doesn’t explain the rather puzzling behaviour. In fact, I’m assuming that’s a bug in the typeface.

Comment: It could be a glyph issue with the `woff2` file - since @Sean narrowed it down to that format.

Comment: Agree with @KonradRudolph. Perhaps there's a newer version of the typeface that addresses this issue?